# Is auspicious place for marriage as important as auspicious time?

Tags: scripture, marriage, time

In Hinduism, it is customary to consider auspicious time for marriage. It can be found across several scriptures. Consider the following as an example for it from [Valmiki Ramayana](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/)

> "Oh, Brahman, the savants acclaim that **part of the day as the best for
>   wedding ceremonies** when both of the pre-Phalguni and post-Phalguni
>   stars are available, and on such a time where post-Phalguni is ruling,
>   for which Bhaga is the presiding deity for progeny..." So said Janaka
>   to the marriage party. [[1-72-13]](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga72/bala_72_frame.htm)

Is it equivalently important to fix auspicious place for marriage? Are there any mentionings about the importance of place for marriage in scriptures?

Comment: We worship prithvi before any ceremony also worship ashta dikpalas , akasha and pray to ganesha  for removing all obstacles . Also in olden times people used to clean the place with cow dunk and cow urine performing vastu puja before ceremony.All this just makes any place auspicious. And after all all earth is auspicious. No part of it is not.

Comment: Yes. Some Kshetras are auspicious for marriage. Puranas mention them.